# how to extract text from moz addon on chrome using iMacros?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, imacros

so i've installed "moz" add on for google chrome (it helps me getting seo results & PA ratings for any search made on google). normally, i can use imacros to scrapte data from any website, but I am unable to scrape data that displays on google search after installing this "moz" extension as it is not part of the HTML codes. Can someone please help me get a fix to this? any help is much appreciated. :)

Comment: What do you see when pressing 'Ctrl+U' ("View page source")? Perhaps the [`SEARCH` command](http://wiki.imacros.net/SEARCH) could help you.

Comment: Since this is not a HTML element, iMacros won't let me extract this data... So how do I make iMacros to extract this content? :O

Comment: What element is that? What do you see when pressing 'Ctrl+U' ("View page source")?

Comment: well when i press, CTRL+U, this doesn't come up in the "View Page Source" as it is not a part of the website itself. It's all about an extension called "Moz" available for download from "https://moz.com/products/pro/seo-toolbar" and works only on Chrome browsers. Only after installing this extension to Chrome and then searching for anything on Google will give results along with this extension and some corresponding values for each result gets displayed below the result.. This image explains it - "http://prntscr.com/ebu82h" and i want to be able to extract only the red highlighted box.

Comment: and when you click on the element and inspect it on the browser, this is what shows up - "http://prnt.sc/ebu94m".

Comment: I hope my answer deserves to be accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this macro for Google search results:

```
SET S "(function() {var elsH3 = document.getElementsByTagName('h3');"
ADD S "for (i = 0; i < elsH3.length; i++)"
ADD S "elsH3[i].setAttribute('mozbarpa', window.frames[i + 2].document.querySelector('div.title').innerHTML.match(/\\d+/));})()"
URL GOTO=javascript:{{S}}

SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=H3 ATTR=CLASS:"r" EXTRACT=HTM
SET mozBarPA EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/mozbarpa="(.*?)"/)[1];")
PROMPT {{mozBarPA}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
```

(Play it in loop mode if needed.)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your efforts on this buddy.. I will run it on my machine and revert back with results

Comment: hey buddy... just one word - Brilliant. You are simply awesome... i was struggling with this for about 1 week day and night.. This is so complicated, yet awesome.. thanks a lot again.. :)

Comment: Also, i have just one more request. Could you please explain what's happening on the 1st 3 lines please?? As i am having a tuff time understanding it... :)

Comment: Hey, these lines are just a workaround to get the data which 'iMacros for Chrome' can't extract directly. Or it's a sort of tricks if you want. Read something about JavaScript (& bookmarklets) and you'll understand a lot!